# Need SOME help decrypt xxtea encrypted Lua file from cocos2D game LIBRARY

Tags: ida, android, ghidra, game-hacking, lua

iam trying from a while to figure out the key this cocos2dx game but couldn't figure it out if someone could abit help with the way to find these keys

you check the the file from here https://github.com/abm9111/libcocos2dlua-/blob/8548dbc35e3ebe62f7e6eab88e81de162f205381/libcocos2dlua.zip

[image]